# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (file writing)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program to take an input file of strings, then to translate them from various languages into English using googletrans. It was working then randomly stopped and kept giving the error code.

At first I was using utf-8, but had to switch to utf_16 for encoding. I also worked through to remove emojis using the emoji module.

```py
from googletrans import Translator
import emoji
translator = Translator()
tweets = set()
for line in open('tweets.txt', encoding='utf_16'):
    line = emoji.demojize(line)
    print(line)
    line = translator.translate(line).text
    line = emoji.emojize(line)
    print(line)
tweets.add(line)
f = open('tweets_without_repeats.txt', 'w', encoding='utf_16')
for i in tweets:
    f.write(i)
f.close()
```

Prints the first line without emojis but before it translates

```
'''File "c:/Users/balle/OneDrive/Documents/IT and Societ Paper/tweet_no_repeats.py", line 8, in <module>  
    line = translator.translate(line).text  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 172, in translate  
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 81, in _translate  
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 62, in format_json  
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json  
    converted = json.loads(text)  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads  
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode  
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())  
  File "c:\Users\balle\Miniconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode  
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None  
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)  
'''
```

Comment: Eroror `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` can mean: it tries to read JSON data but it is empty, or it is incorrectly formated and first line is empty. Error shows problem in `line = translator.translate(line).text ` so use `print()` to see values in variables before this line.

Comment: I do print before the translation, as is in my code, and it prints it correctly as I stated before showing the error message.